# Redirecionamento para tela de login constantemente ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, iis, web.config

constantemnte durante a navegação do site o usuário está sendo redirecionado para a tela de login. Eu mesmo fico navegando em várias telas clicando nos menus e de forma aleatória o sistema vai para o login. Já coloquei o timeout da sessão com um tempo bastante elevado e não consegui descobrir. Já tenho várias semanas trabalhando nisso e sem solução. Podem ajudar? segue o meu webconfig.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
      EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
      PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
 </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
     <add name="DefaultConnection" 
  connectionString="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
 </appSettings>
 <system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="false"/>

 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
 <authentication mode="None"></authentication>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
 <httpModules>
   <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
 </httpModules>
```

Comment: Já resolveu o problema? Você não não tem alguma configuração que ao jogar uma exceção o logoff é realizado?

Comment: Não resolvi, eu tenho pouca experiência com asp.net publicado em site, normalmente uso intenamente e não tenho problemas. Eu não sei como fazer a exceção que vc diz. Tem algum link que possa me ajudar? eu suspeito que o problema seja aonde a aplicação está hospedada

Comment: RESOLVIDO, o problema era a machine key no web.config. Como estava usando a hospedagem do tipo farm, a aplicação perdia o token, Apenas acrescentei a linha abaixo e resolveu.  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="83BDD6F29FEF43C0256106B322F775DE77D8704CC3A5E07B9D2BD2253337374A3A64DD466D6A2CA81C6FBF27F6BFF637FC24CE8C17B0540BB191E07B90CB5DC0" decryptionKey="4411595512AD6A65D5C09842DB764FA1BAAC04A37FD6C7E4827D42ED8F8C496E" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, o problema era a `machineKey` no `web.config`. Como estava usando a hospedagem do tipo farm, a aplicação perdia o token. Apenas acrescentei a linha abaixo e resolveu.

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="83BDD6F29FEF43C0256106B322F775DE77D8704CC3A5E07B9D2BD2253337374A3A64DD466D6A2CA81C6FBF27F6BFF637FC24CE8C17B0540BB191E07B90CB5DC0" decryptionKey="4411595512AD6A65D5C09842DB764FA1BAAC04A37FD6C7E4827D42ED8F8C496E" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```